# how to set start up serial number in sql query?

Tags: sql-server, row-number, sql-query-store

I ever use `row_number()` but it start with auto number. i want to set default value start by myself.

ex:

```
row_number() Over (Order by OrderNumber)
```

result:

```
1. a 
2. B
3. C
```

but is it possible to do this?

```
101. A
102. B
103. C
```

Your answer is very important!!!

Comment: `row_number() Over (Order by OrderNumber) + 100`

Comment: wow. That's look awesome. i will try it thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the row_number() + add a number to it:

```
 SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyColumnName) + 100) AS Rn, * FROM MyTableName
```

Comment: sorry. i am new. could you tell me how to vote? i will do it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @ab:=@ab+1 as SrNo,* FROM tablename, (SELECT @ab:= 100) AS ab;
```